# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'NSStoryboard.Name'

Tags: swift

I'm trying the following in swift:

```
var storyboard = NSStoryboard.init(name: "Actors", bundle: nil)
```

This generates an error: **Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'NSStoryboard.Name'**

According to the class reference `NSStoryboard.Name` should be a string without the file extension, which I supply.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve the issue

```
var storyboard = NSStoryboard.init(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Actors"), bundle: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

`NSStoryboard.Name` got its own scope in the namespace to be able to do that:

```
extension NSStoryboard.Name {
    static let actors = NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Actors")
}
```

---

```
let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: .actors, bundle: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enum Storyboards: String {
   case main = "Main"

   func instantiateVC<T>(_ identifier: T.Type) -> T?  {
      let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: rawValue, bundle: nil)
      guard let viewcontroller = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: String(describing: identifier)) as? T else { return nil}
      return viewcontroller
  }
}

//Usage
let tabViewController = Storyboards.main.instantiateVC(IDTabViewController.self)
window!.contentViewController = tabViewController
```